# how to use functions and return statement with for loop in python

Tags: python, function, loops

```
def calculation(numbers):
    for i in range(1,11):
        maths = i * numbers
        result = print(f"{numbers} x {i} = {maths}")
    return result


user_input = int(input('enter a number: '))
x = calculation(user_input)
print(x)
```

So this is a multiplication program using for loop.

when am returning "result" its doing the calculations but after that its returning NONE
why is it doing that? and what is the fix for it?

I tried returning "maths" but its only returning the last iteration I don't want that,
I want to see all the iterations.

Comment: `print(...)` returns None.

Comment: `result = f"{numbers} x {i} = {maths}"` try this.

Comment: its only returning the last iteration

Comment: You need to be clear what your function is supposed to do. What exactly do you want the function to print? What do you want the function to return? (one value? multiple values? Numbers? Strings?) Without this, any answe is just guesswork.

Comment: so if I want multiple values what should I use then and am guessing if I want one value I just use return

Answer (score 0):

The print() should be removed.

Comment: but then how can I let it to show the 10 iterations without the print the statement ?